# NextJS response.json converts decimal to string

Tags: json, next.js

Api handler in NextJS converts decimal to string.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();

  const result = await prisma.Test.findMany({});
  console.log(result);
  res.status(200).json(result);
  //res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe", age: 34, salary: 12345.75 });
};

export default handler;
```

This returns
[{"id":"dafsdfd","name":"John Doe","age":35,"salary":"1234.56","updatedAt":"2023-11-21T08:45:55.000Z"}]

Though the console log prints correctly as follows.
[
{
id: 'dafsdfd',
name: 'John Doe',
age: 35,
salary: 1234.56,
updatedAt: 2023-11-21T08:45:55.000Z
}
]

However, if I use
res.status(200).json({ name: "John Doe", age: 34, salary: 12345.75 });
It is returing the decimal correctly as below.

How can I return a decimal from an object without converting to string in NextJS ?